# Найти наименьшее число в массиве под четным номером и наибольшее под нечетным?

Tags: java

Ниже я привожу свое решение. Мне кажется, оно неверно.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] arr = new int[] {5,10,2,4,3,7,5,3,7,4};
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++);
            if(i < arr[i])
            if((i%2) == 0){

                X = arr[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(X);

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if((i%2) == 1){
                if(arr[i] > i)
                Y = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Y);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Отладчик используйте...

Comment: Я дебажил только не совсем понимаю почемуоно так происходит поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Было бы очень неплохо добавить как же именно оно происходит и что вы получили при использовании отладчика.

Comment: Проходит 10 элементов для Х и для У и получаю 5 и 7 У правильно а Х должен быть 3 а получается 5 .

Comment: Почему X должен быть 3? arr[2] = 2 - минимальное значение в массиве с четным индексом. Смотрите в отладчике что происходит.

Comment: возможна вы и правы

Comment: Вас не смущает, что индексация у вас в коде при этом с нуля? И какой же индекс у элемента массива, равного двум?

Comment: я экспериментирую сейчас уже вижу что это неправильно

Comment: В общем, отладчик - ваш лучший друг.

Comment: Оно то так только я не совсемпонимаю что там нужно смотреть и как это понимать ((

Comment: @Андрей при отладке все просто, шагаете по строкам и смотрите какие значения принимают переменные, на каждом шаге думаете с помощью головы думаете и делаете выводы

Answer (score 1):

Замучили человека, ошибка сразу в нескольких строках.

```
int [] arr = new int[] {5,10,2,4,3,7,5,3,7,4};
int X = arr[0];
int Y = arr[1];

for(int i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {

   if((i % 2) == 0) {
       if (arr[i] < X) {
                X = arr[i];
       }
   } else {
       if (arr[i] > Y) {
                Y = arr[i];
       }
   }
```

Comment: давайте не будем обижать друг друга!

Comment: Не совсем то что я хотел есть задача 10 чифр это вагоны поезда и надо найти наименьшее количество мест в четных вагонах и наибольшее в нечетных , а сдесь решено как наибольший и наименьший в массиве но за такое решение тоже спасибо!!!

Comment: Решение задачи в точности подходит по ваш заголовок "Найти наименьшее число в массиве под четным номером и наибольшее под нечетным?"

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы и замечания.